# Bootstrap Multiselect Limit Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a multiselect dropdown using [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) .
I need to set a limit in options selection (Here I set it to 5) and if the limit reached I just disabled the other select optons and it Works Perfectly. But the problem is When I tried to select more than 5 using SHIFT key. It doesn't work(means my jQuery to prevent selection not work) and I can select more than 5. Please Check the Snippet and give me a solution.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/adhershmnair/z5z98pLa/)

```js
 jQuery('#soft_skill_list').multiselect({
        enableFiltering: true,
        maxHeight:400,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering:true, 
        nonSelectedText: 'Soft Skills *', 
        numberDisplayed: 2, 
        selectAll: false, 
        onChange: function(option, checked) {
                // Get selected options.
                var selectedOptions = jQuery('#soft_skill_list option:selected');
 
                if (selectedOptions.length >= 5) {
                    // Disable all other checkboxes.
                    var nonSelectedOptions = jQuery('#soft_skill_list option').filter(function() {
                        return !jQuery(this).is(':selected');
                    });
 
                    nonSelectedOptions.each(function() {
                        var input = jQuery('input[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]');
                        input.prop('disabled', true);
                        input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // Enable all checkboxes.
                    jQuery('#soft_skill_list option').each(function() {
                        var input = jQuery('input[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]');
                        input.prop('disabled', false);
                        input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                    });
                }
            }});
```

```html
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

<select name="soft_skill_list[]" class="soft_skill_list"  id="soft_skill_list" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Analysing data</option>
  <option>Banquets Operations</option>
  <option>Concierge Operations</option>
  <option>Customer service experience</option>
  <option>Measuring and calculating</option>
  <option>Micros</option>
  <option>Numeracy Skills </option>
  <option>Opening Hotels</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
  <option>Outside catering</option>
  <option>Pre-opening</option>
  <option>Procedures </option>
  <option>Proficiency in computer programming</option>
  <option>Public speaking experience </option>
  <option>Reservation</option>
  <option>Restaurants operations</option>
  <option>Revenue Analysis</option>
  <option>Rooms Division</option>
  <option>Safety and Security</option>
  <option>Sales administration</option>
  <option>Sales Operations</option>
  <option>Social Media</option>
</select>
```

Please Check image [image: Attached image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Need to Block Shift key When Clicking the list option.
Try the  Below jQuery.

> Please Check it Out Here -> [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1ejby1qf/)

```
var shiftClick = jQuery.Event("click");
shiftClick.shiftKey = true;

    $(".multiselect-container li *").click(function(event) {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
           //alert("Shift key is pressed");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            //alert('No shift hey');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please Update in jsfiddle. Though I can Check

Comment: Please wait... Will Update Now

Comment: Oh That's Working. Awesome. Thanks. @Arun

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate separately if more than 5 options are selected.

```
if (selectedOptions.length >= 5) {
  if (selectedOptions.length > 5) {
    // Show error
  } else {
    // What you do already
  }
```

When checkboxes are selected one at the time, they can never exceed 5.

Comment: I tried this. But It Doesnt Work. Would You Please Update new code to fiddle. And show its working.

Comment: Its Just Showing an Alert. But Doesn't Prevent the selectioon of option. It still continuing the issue. I want not to be Select if we choose more than 5.

Comment: I think you get my problem? Is it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I understand. Let me get a fix for that.

Comment: Ok. Thank You @Gerard

Comment: This takes more time than I anticipated :(

Comment: Yes. I tried a lot. Please suggest any programmer you know to solve this. It will be a big help. @Gerard.

Comment: I never thought I was going to say this, but it seems impossible. https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/ytdpvmu2/2/ Looks like the saved copy is even changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one multiselect in the same page with the same option value, make sure that you add the correct selector function when you are enabling/disabling the checkboxes, you have to replace this line

```
    var input = jQuery('input[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]');
```

for this

```
    var input = jQuery('#soft_skill_list + .btn-group input[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]');
```

Otherwise you will be disabling other checkboxes in the other multiselect controls as well.

I will be it like this:

```
jQuery('#soft_skill_list').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight:400,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering:true, 
    nonSelectedText: 'Soft Skills *', 
    numberDisplayed: 2, 
    selectAll: false, 
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
            // Get selected options.
            var selectedOptions = jQuery('#soft_skill_list option:selected');

            if (selectedOptions.length >= 5) {
                // Disable all other checkboxes.
                var nonSelectedOptions = jQuery('#soft_skill_list option').filter(function() {
                    return !jQuery(this).is(':selected');
                });

                nonSelectedOptions.each(function() {
                    var input = jQuery('#soft_skill_list + .btn-group input[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]');
                    input.prop('disabled', true);
                    input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                });
            }
            else {
                // Enable all checkboxes.
                jQuery('#soft_skill_list option').each(function() {
                    var input = jQuery('#soft_skill_list + .btn-group  input[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]');
                    input.prop('disabled', false);
                    input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                });
            }
        }});
```